# What is a 'farmer' in American English?

Tags: american-english

When Americans talk about *farmers* what do they mean?

In Britain a 'farmer' is someone who either owns the land that he or she works, or is the tenant of the land. It is the person who decides what crops to grow and has overall management of the enterprise.

People who work the land as employees of the farm are known variously as *farm workers*, *agricultural labourers*, or simply *employees*.

I have the sense that when Americans talk about *farmers* they mean something wider than we do. Is that the case?

Comment: I don’t think so. I use it like you do. There may be some who use it other than you and I do, but I’d have to see specific examples of the sort that led to this question.

Comment: In the US a "farmer" is generally someone in the farming business -- someone who grows crops or livestock and sells them to make money.  But there's no word police to prevent someone from calling himself a "farmer" if he doesn't fit that description.  And in the US there are lots of variations between "owner" and "tenant" -- someone may own all of their land, just part of it, or very little.  However, someone who owns land and doesn't farm it but rents it all out is not usually considered a "farmer" (though he may choose to call himself one).

Comment: And note that some livestock farmers may resent that term and prefer to be called "ranchers".

Comment: 20.5K rep means a pass on reporting no research? Interesting. Anyhow, here in the U.S. the decision on what crops to plant seems to be mostly left up to the Monsanto corporation and their hireling pols in Washington, sad to say.

Comment: @HotLicks But as regards someone who didn't own or lease land, but was let's say a farm manager, would they call themselves a 'farmer'?

Comment: @WS2 - If the person in question is not the "owner" of the business but "manages" a farm on behalf of someone else -- telling others what to do and deciding when to buy and sell stuff -- then he would probably call himself a "farm manager".  But if he is the principal person who literally gets up on the tractor and plows the fields he's probably a "farmer".  But, once again, no one is checking what people call themselves.

Comment: @tchrist I didn't have any specific examples in mind other than the recent question on this site which contained an extract that said in 1880, 78% of the American population were 'farmers'. But I have previously had the general impression that 'farmer' was used more liberally in America.

Comment: [In the 1800s, 90 percent of the population lived on farms; today it is around one percent.](http://www.pbs.org/ktca/farmhouses/sustainable_future.html)

Comment: @tchrist The '1800s' covers a wide spread of history. I would somehow doubt that as late as 1880, 78% of the population actually worked on farms, let alone their being 'farmers', wouldn't you? In Britain, by 1914, only 9% of the population were engaged in agriculture. It was especially low in the UK, by far the lowest in Europe, since Britain had come to depend on the Commonwealth. It also explains why in both world wars Britain had such a critical problem in feeding its population.

Comment: [In 1880, 71.8% of the US population were classified as rural.](https://www.census.gov/population/censusdata/table-4.pdf)

Comment: @tchrist Those are quite remarkable figures. But the key lies in what is described as 'rural' I suppose.

Comment: Who was called a "farmer" in 1880 was probably quite a bit different from who would be called a "farmer" today.  Very little automation, farms were much smaller.  You could probably have counted the number of "farm managers" (in the current sense) on one hand.  (OK, maybe both hands, and a few toes, but such concepts were rare.)  And pretty much everyone who lived "rurally" was a farmer to one degree or another, if only to have a acre of potatoes or some such.

Comment: @tchrist If you look at the question starting *Ambivalence...* from yesterday, you will see that the OP has possibly used the same population statistics which you provided. But they have interpreted the word *rural* to mean 'farmer'. And other contributors here seem to endorse that the word *farmer* is more loosely used in America. In Britain 'farmer' has social significance, as well as occupational, and terminology has perhaps not changed much since the days of Thomas Hardy in the late 19th century. His novels will make clear who we call a 'farmer', and who is a 'farm hand'.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the usage varies with community.

For the vast majority of Americans, who live in urban or suburban communities, a farmer is anyone who makes a living by agricultural labor. This would include farm laborers (called farmhands or ranch hands in the US). Ownership/tenancy is irrelevant.

Within rural communities, I believe the UK distinction is made.

ETA - Upon further reflection, I'll modify this to exclude those who raise animals, especially meat cows (oops - beef cattle). Urban/suburban Americans will probably call these folk, both ranchers and ranch hands, cowboys. Those who raise dairy cows are called farmers. For other animals, such as sheep, I doubt that there is a single term which is widely used. Some would call these farmers, some shepherds.

Comment: This was my suspicion, but @tchrist tends to the view that the word has much the same meaning as in the UK.

Comment: @WS2 I grew up in a rural environment.

Comment: @tchrist You will appreciate Thomas Hardy then!

Answer (score 5):

My grandfather raised beef cattle (Aberdeen Angus) on an 87-acre farm in central Texas, and I remember asking him once why he didn't refer to himself as a "rancher." He laughed and said that anyone who owned less than a hundred acres of land and called himself a rancher was just kidding himself. In Texas (and I assume elsewhere in the United States) you could qualify for membership in the state's Cattlemen's Association whether you ran a farm or a ranch.

As for the question of who qualified as a farmer, I believe that in Texas the main distinctions were between owning or leasing a farm (which made you a farmer), working on a single farm that someone else owned and operated (which made you a hired hand), and working on many farms at harvest season (which made you a member of, say, a hay-baling crew, if that was the job you did, or a migrant worker, if you picked cotton or fruits or vegetables at multiple farms each harvest season and followed the ripening crops northward as the season progressed).

Answer (score 2):

I think "farmer" is used casually by people, especially those from urban areas, to refer to those in some vague agricultural occupation. If the conversation gets at all specific, however, it will sound odd to refer to a day laborer or migrant worker, etc. as a "farmer". Instead the term will change to one of these or to something like "farmhand". Eg.:

"Didn't you say your brother is a farmer?"

"Well, he's trying to be. He got a job on an organic ranch and he's hoping to work his way up."

Maybe along these lines.

Answer (score 0):

One difference I've noticed in America lately is a seeming merger of "farm" woth "ranch". I used to think that animals are raised on a ranch, and crops on a farm. But maybe animals that cannot roam to graze are "farm animals"?

In America there is also the term "factory farms" to refer to operations where animals are forced to spend their whole lives imprisoned in inhumanely close quarters.

Anyway, eggs from a chicken ranch are often labeled "farm fresh".  And I have heard a radio commercial in California in which a guy described himself as owning an "avocado ranch"!  I immediately thought of applying for work herding avocados; it seems it would be easy.  I think city folk just don't understand distinctions between farm, ranch, and orchard.

Comment: There are no "ranches" east of the Mississippi, but there are many cattle farms.

Comment: I guess that would make sense, since "ranch" is from Spanish, and the Spanish/Mexican influence did not reach east of the Mississippi (except for naming Florida).

Comment: In Texas at least, the term "dairy ranch" is little used, even though dairy cattle generally need as much grazing land as beef cattle do. It is far more common to speak of dairy cattle as being raised on "dairy farms," even if the "farm" is ranch-size. As for "chicken ranch," the only time I heard that term used was as the name of a famous brothel in Fayette County, Texas, that was closed down when I was still a lad. Anyone claiming to run a "chicken ranch" in central Texas would undoubtedly have raised some eyebrows and some laughs among the country folk.

Comment: Obviously the word *ranch* is foreign to Europe (except perhaps in Spain). In Britain we have arable farms (crops only), beef farms, dairy farms, 'hill farms' (sheep), and mixed farms. Intensive battery farming of hens is unpopular with consumers, who pay a premium for 'free range' eggs and poultry. The word *orchard* is not normally used in farming ( it is a more domestic word e.g with large houses). Fruit and vegetable farming is known as 'market gardening'.

Comment: UK people familiar with the daily radio soap *The Archers*, (which has run daily since 1951, and is an unavoidable part of British life) will know that David Archer, Tony Archer and Brian Aldridge are *farmers*. Neil Carter is a *pigman* who has risen (almost) to manager status. One-time farmers, the Grundies, are in essence now farm hands. The distinction is as much social, but the underlying criterion is ownership.

Comment: I've always wondered how difficult it is to corral "free range eggs" into cartons.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock That's what makes them more expensive, I assume. The son of an old friend of mine is a duck farmer, supplying duck eggs to the Chinese restaurant trade. The ducks are housed indoors but are free to run around. The daily collecting of the eggs is the most labour-intensive part of the job and I think they pay the youngster who does it by the egg!